# How to get the "Internet Domain" and "Address name format" using interop.domino.dll c# program?

Tags: c#, lotus-domino, interop-domino

[image: Domino Internet Domain information]

How to get the internet domain and format information ? Since those information are needed in user registration process to set up internet address of the user.

Comment: Do you want this information for a user who was already registered? Or do you want it because you are registering more users?

Comment: I want to register more users so i want to know the format and domain so that i can use those information in back-end to set internet address of the user.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple environment you should be able to find the information in the names.nsf in the global domain document. see view 'Sever\Domains'

Comment: When i am looking into "Sever\Domains" the view there is no entry in it.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to find the address name format. It's not stored anywhere. (Yes, there's a format in the Global Domain document, but that's for creating return addresses for users who don't actually have an assigned internet address - a remnant from way back in the early days before we routinely assigned an internet address to each user. An organization may have a different rule for handling those "legacy user" cases than the format that they currently use for new users.) The value you are looking for is really a choice that you enter each time when registering users, and that's the only place it's ever relevant. You can pick a different format each time and Domino doesn't care. If you want to set a default for your own application, you can store it in your application's configuration.

The internet domain can, in theory, be read from the Global Domain document or from Internet Site documents, in names.nsf, but that's plural: One server can support multiple sites with different domain names. The one in the Global Domain document is the "primary" name, but that doesn't necessarily imply that it's the one you want to use for registering new users! Some organizations, for example, use a different domain name for users depending on what country they or in or what division they are in. I can't really think of any way that you could distinguish which one of the domain names you would find in names.nsf is the one that you should be using for any given registration. Again, if you want to provide a default value, you can store it in your application's configuration.

Comment: Thank You for the valuable explanation , To read primary domain of the domino server how can use names.nsf file problematically ?

Comment: The primary domain name will most likely be found in the Global Domain document in the field named LocalPrimaryInternetDomain. You can also probably derive it from the HTTP_HostName field in the Server document, or from the ISiteAdrs field (which is multi-valued0 in the SMTP Inbound Site document.

Comment: I have opened Domino Admin console and looked into Configuration->Messaging->Domains there are no entries in it.
The Http_HostName property is empty in server document.

Comment: Since in our domino server environment no extra Global domain is added i will be taking domain from Primary Domino Suffix of the computer.